# Replace extension from certain links

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, hyperlink, href

i have an array, which includes some pages:

```
var pages = ['test', 'blabla', 'xyz'];
```

My document contains some links like these:

```
<a href="test.php">tes</a>
<a href="blabla.php">blabla</a>
<a href="xyz.php">xyz</a>
<a href="stackoverflow.php">test2</a>
```

What i want is the following:

I want to search the whole document and find all links, that are starting with the words in my array. Then, i want to replace ".php" with ".html" and prepend the current URL (without the file) to them:

```
location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

So, the expected result should look like this:

```
<a href="file:///C:/test.html">test</a>
<a href="file:///C:/blabla.html">blabla</a>
<a href="file:///C:/xyz.html">xyz</a>
<a href="stackoverflow.php">xyz</a>
```

What i tried is this:

```
$(function(){
var pages = ['test', 'blabla', 'xyz'];
$.each(pages, function(index, value) {
$("a[href='" + value + ".php']").attr("href", location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1) + $("a[href='" + value + ".php']").attr("href").replace('php', 'html'));
});
});
```

This works, but not always. I tried this in a bigger document and it ends with this error:

> $("a[href='" + value + ".php']").attr("href") is undefined

I guess, there's an easier, better and more compatible way. But i have no clue, that's why i ask here :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pages = ['test', 'blabla', 'xyz'];
$.each(pages, function (index, value) {
    $('a[href$=' + value + '.php]').attr("href", function () {
        return ('file:///C:/' + $(this).attr('href').replace('.php', '.html'));
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked with a small change. I had to change $('a[href$=' + value + '.php]') to $("a[href$='" + value + ".php']")

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var pages = ['test', 'blabla', 'xyz'];   
$('a[href$=".php"]').each(function() {
  var hrefWithoutext = this.href.replace('.php','');
  if($.inArray(hrefWithoutext, pages)){
    this.href = 'file:///C:/' + hrefWithoutext + '.html';
  }
});​
```